# Salesforce - Wildcard - My Acceptable Email Addresses - accept all emails

Tags: email

I would like to have `"Email to Salesforce"` accept all emails that are sent to my unique Email to Salesforce email.

So I need to know how to add **wildcards** to allow all emails.

The setting I am referring to is located at: `Your Name | Setup | Email | My Email to Salesforce >> My Acceptable Email Addresses`

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at some custom Apex code that can parse incoming email sent from any address. This functionality is called "Inbound Email Service" and Jeff Douglas (as always!) has a great write-up: https://www.jeffdouglas.com/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com

Answer (score 1):

Not supported in any form, as far as I know. If you want to be able to support inbound emails from disparate sources you'll have to look at a custom solution. Another possibility would be to set up a mail relay that re-packages the email into SFDC as "from" one of your acceptable email addresses, but that sounds less than desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have gotten it to work where the email is forwarded from an acceptable email address - but to do that I have to have 2x TO headers in the email - the acceptable email and the users - then Salesforce finds the Users email in the TO header and adds it to the lead as an activity - only down side is the user also receives an email.